# C# Win. Form - How to send email with secured gmail id?

Tags: c#, winforms, security, email, gmail

Recently, i have experienced that many of my clients have **secured gmail id** (some have 2 step verification, some email id show **blocked sign in attempt**) and are not willing to turn down their security but want to send email with it.

Can anyone suggest me of a way to send email without compromising security?

**Current E-Mail Code**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");             
mail.From = new MailAddress("fromaddress@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("toaddress1@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("toaddress2@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Password Recovery ";
mail.Body += " <html>";
mail.Body += "<body>";
mail.Body += "<table>";
mail.Body += "<tr>";
mail.Body += "<td>User Name : </td><td> HAi </td>";
mail.Body += "</tr>";

mail.Body += "<tr>";
mail.Body += "<td>Password : </td><td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>";
mail.Body += "</tr>";
mail.Body += "</table>";
mail.Body += "</body>";
mail.Body += "</html>";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sendfrommailaddress.com", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an application specific password that will bypass the 2 factor authentication:

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthSettings#asps

Also, you should never send username and passwords via email. Send a temporary nonce URL to reset a password -or- if you must, send the password via another channel, like SMS or Snail Mail. Ideally passwords should never be saved, only hashed and salted (and possibly peppered)